# Load sqlite extensions via Sequelize

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js, node-sqlite3

I have some sqlite3 extension and I can load it via `sqlite3` package:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:')
db.loadExtension('./myExt')
```

And now this extension is awailable. But how to load it via Sequelize?

I have tried:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:')
sequelize.query("SELECT load_extension('./myExt')")
```

But there is `SQLITE_ERROR: not authorized`. And this error is normal, [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1123) was said that I have to use `loadExtension` API, but how can I access to it via Sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the only solution by using Proxy:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
sqlite3.Database = new Proxy(sqlite3.Database, {
  construct (target, args) {
    const db = new target(...args)
    db.loadExtension('./myExt')
    return db
  }
})
```

And now after:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:')
```

Instance of `Sequilize` will use sqlite extension. But I am still interested, is there some more simple way to do it without Proxy, only with Sequelize.